# Worldwind Render Order of Surface Shapes and Tactical Symbols

Tags: java, arcgis, layer, worldwind

Essentially, I would like Surface Shapes to be rendered on top of Tactical Symbols by default. Here is the problem recreated in a Worldwind Example

```
public class TestApp extends ApplicationTemplate {

public static class AppFrame extends ApplicationTemplate.AppFrame {

    public AppFrame() {

        // Symbol
        RenderableLayer symbolLayer = new RenderableLayer();

        TacticalSymbol symbol = new MilStd2525TacticalSymbol("suzp-----------", Position.fromDegrees(0.0, 0.0));
        symbol.setAltitudeMode(WorldWind.CLAMP_TO_GROUND);
        symbol.setShowLocation(false);
        symbolLayer.addRenderable(symbol);

        // Shape
        RenderableLayer shapeLayer = new RenderableLayer();
        SurfaceCircle circle = new SurfaceCircle(Position.fromDegrees(0.0, 0.0), 100e4);
        shapeLayer.addRenderable(circle);

        getWwd().getModel().getLayers().add(symbolLayer);
        getWwd().getModel().getLayers().add(shapeLayer);
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    start("World Wind Testing", AppFrame.class);
}
}
```

[image]

No matter which order I add the layers in, the Tactical Symbol is always rendered on top of the Surface Shape. I'm assuming this is because shapes are rendered differently:

> "layers are displayed in the order they’re defined in the layer list. (3D shapes within layers, however, are displayed in far-to-near order"

I have a hunch that I can solve this problem by extending Tactical Symbol and implementing the *OrderedRenderable* interface and overriding the *makeOrderedRenderable()* method but I'm unsure as to which specific changes I should make to achieve the desired functionality without breaking other layers.

Comment: I don't suppose you ever figured this out?

Comment: unfortunately no. It's still an issue.

Comment: I think your problem is similar (not exactly same) to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44305310/5538979): see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44546335/5538979. I hope it be useful for you.