# Worldwind - Shapes are always displayed on top of images?

Tags: gis, shapes, layer, raster, worldwind

I have two layers added to the layerlist of WorldWindowGLJPanel. One of them is RenderableLayer which contain shapes and the other is BasicTiledImageLayer containing raster images. (One layer contains one object). The problem is when i change the order of layers with layermanager panel, only the order of objects that have the same type of layer changes and shapes are always displayed on top of images no matter which order they have. Is there a way to correct this?

Screenshots:

[image: Only raster is shown (selected)]

[image: Both raster and shape selected]

[image: Both raster and shape selected (zoom out)]

[image: Both raster and shape selected (display order changed)]

And my code is as follows:

```
    /*
 * Copyright (C) 2012 United States Government as represented by the Administrator of the
 * National Aeronautics and Space Administration.
 * All Rights Reserved.
 */
package gov.nasa.worldwindx.examples;

import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;

import gov.nasa.worldwind.BasicFactory;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.WorldWind;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.avlist.AVKey;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.avlist.AVList;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.avlist.AVListImpl;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.cache.FileStore;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.data.TiledImageProducer;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.formats.shapefile.ShapefileLayerFactory;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.formats.shapefile.ShapefileRecord;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.formats.shapefile.ShapefileRenderable;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.geom.Sector;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.layers.Layer;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.util.Logging;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.util.WWIO;
import gov.nasa.worldwindx.examples.dataimport.DataInstallUtil;
import gov.nasa.worldwindx.examples.util.ExampleUtil;
import gov.nasa.worldwindx.examples.util.RandomShapeAttributes;

/**
 * Illustrates how to import ESRI Shapefiles into World Wind. This uses a <code>{@link ShapefileLayerFactory}</code> to
 * parse a Shapefile's contents and convert the shapefile into an equivalent World Wind shape.
 *
 * @version $Id: Shapefiles.java 3212 2015-06-18 02:45:56Z tgaskins $
 */
public class ShapeRaster extends ApplicationTemplate
{
    protected static final String BASE_CACHE_PATH = "Examples/"; // Define a subdirectory in the installed-data area

    // This example's imagery is loaded from the following class-path resource.
    protected static final String IMAGE_PATH = "gov/nasa/worldwindx/examples/data/craterlake-imagery-30m.tif";

    public static class AppFrame extends ApplicationTemplate.AppFrame
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -7733929990972508866L;

        public AppFrame()
        {
            ShapefileLayerFactory factory = new ShapefileLayerFactory();

            // Specify an attribute delegate to assign random attributes to each shape file record.
            final RandomShapeAttributes randomAttrs = new RandomShapeAttributes();
            factory.setAttributeDelegate(new ShapefileRenderable.AttributeDelegate()
            {
                @Override
                public void assignAttributes(ShapefileRecord shapefileRecord,
                    ShapefileRenderable.Record renderableRecord)
                {
                    renderableRecord.setAttributes(randomAttrs.nextAttributes().asShapeAttributes());
                }
            });

            // Load the shape file. Define the completion callback.
            factory.createFromShapefileSource("testData/shapefiles/TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.shp",
                new ShapefileLayerFactory.CompletionCallback()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void completion(Object result)
                    {
                        final Layer layer = (Layer) result; // the result is the layer the factory created
                        layer.setName(WWIO.getFilename(layer.getName()));
                        layer.clearList();

                        // Add the layer to the World Window's layer list on the Event Dispatch Thread.
                        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void run()
                            {
                                AppFrame.this.getWwd().getModel().getLayers().add(layer);
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void exception(Exception e)
                    {
                        Logging.logger().log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
                    }
                });

            // Show the WAIT cursor because the installation may take a while.
            this.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR));

            // Install the imagery on a thread other than the event-dispatch thread to avoid freezing the UI.
            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    installImagery();

                    // Restore the cursor.
                    setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
                }
            });

            t.start();
        }

        protected void installImagery()
        {
            // Download the source file.
            File sourceFile = ExampleUtil.saveResourceToTempFile(IMAGE_PATH, ".tif");

            // Get a reference to the FileStore into which we'll install the imagery.
            FileStore fileStore = WorldWind.getDataFileStore();

            // Install the imagery into the FileStore.
            final Layer layer = installSurfaceImage("Crater Lake Imagery 30m", sourceFile, fileStore);
            if (layer == null)
                return;

            // Display a layer with the new imagery. Must do it on the event dispatch thread.
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    // Add the layer created by the install method to the layer list.
                    insertBeforePlacenames(AppFrame.this.getWwd(), layer);

                    // Set the view to look at the installed image. Get the location from the layer's construction
                    // parameters.
                    AVList params = (AVList) layer.getValue(AVKey.CONSTRUCTION_PARAMETERS);
                    Sector sector = (Sector) params.getValue(AVKey.SECTOR);
                    ExampleUtil.goTo(getWwd(), sector);
                }
            });
        }

        protected Layer installSurfaceImage(String displayName, Object imageSource, FileStore fileStore)
        {
            // Use the FileStore's install location as the destination for the installed imagery. The default install
            // location is the FileStore's area for permanent storage.
            File fileStoreLocation = DataInstallUtil.getDefaultInstallLocation(fileStore);

            // Create a unique cache name that specifies the installed data's location within the FileStore.
            String cacheName = BASE_CACHE_PATH + WWIO.replaceIllegalFileNameCharacters(displayName);

            // Create a parameter list specifying the install location information.
            AVList params = new AVListImpl();
            params.setValue(AVKey.FILE_STORE_LOCATION, fileStoreLocation.getAbsolutePath());
            params.setValue(AVKey.DATA_CACHE_NAME, cacheName);
            params.setValue(AVKey.DATASET_NAME, displayName);

            // Create a TiledImageProducer to install the imagery.
            TiledImageProducer producer = new TiledImageProducer();
            try
            {
                // Configure the TiledImageProducer with the parameter list and the image source.
                producer.setStoreParameters(params);
                producer.offerDataSource(imageSource, null);

                // Install the imagery.
                producer.startProduction();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                producer.removeProductionState(); // Clean up on failure.
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }

            // Extract the data configuration document from the installed results. If the installation successfully
            // completed, the TiledImageProducer should always contain a document in the production results, but test
            // the results anyway.
            Iterable<?> results = producer.getProductionResults();
            if (results == null || results.iterator() == null || !results.iterator().hasNext())
                return null;

            Object o = results.iterator().next();
            if (o == null || !(o instanceof Document))
                return null;

            // Construct a Layer by passing the data configuration document to a LayerFactory.
            Layer layer = (Layer) BasicFactory.create(AVKey.LAYER_FACTORY, ((Document) o).getDocumentElement());

            // The layer factory creates layers that are initially disabled, so enable the layer.
            layer.setEnabled(true);

            return layer;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        start("World Wind Shapefiles", AppFrame.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on created shapes for data in your shapefile. Created shapes by ShapefileLayerFactory may be of type surface shapes such as SurfacePlygon or SurfaceCircle. These shapes are always on top of images. Other shapes such as ExtrudedPolygon may have altitude. For this type of shapes, if altitude is upper than 0 it will be over images anyway.